# NavigationBar How to Title Font color font style

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I understand that you are able to change the title of a Navigation item by calling the SetTitle method navigationItem like so:

```
[[ViewController navigationItem] setTitle:@"Hello World"];
```

However, i would like to do more then just change the text of the Navigation Item, I would like to change the colour and font style.

Are there any functions that allow you to change the colour of the Navigation Bar Title?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply add and modify the following code in viewdidload method. Or you even can put a image on the navigation bar

```
if ([[UINavigationBar class]respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
    UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor whiteColor],
    UITextAttributeTextShadowColor : [UIColor blackColor],
    UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset : [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(1, 0)],
    UITextAttributeFont : [UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:25.0]
}];
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I just checked the API and it looks like the titleTextAttributes function is what i'm looking for. However, it's only available for IOS5. I'm still using iPhone sdk 4.3, i seem to be finding a lot of functions that are available in IOS5 only. I might sign up for the developer program to play with these features.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this tutorial, http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

Answer (score 0):

Each UINavigationController's navigation bar is made up of navigation items. You can use the UINavigationItem property titleView, and return to it a custom view that contains whatever font size, color, style, etc. that you want.